# How to set selected value of jQuery chosen?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, yii2

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#state").change(function () {
        var stateId = $("#state").val()
            phpurl = "sample_url" + stateId;

            $.ajax({
                url: phpurl,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#district").html(data).trigger("chosen:updated");                        
                },
                 error: function(data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Above is my code to generate district based on state, and it works fine. I just want set the value what is selected by user. At present the selected value is cleared after selecting a state and submit.

Comment: Can you more specific what is happening. Which selected value is cleared 'District' or 'state' drop down?

Comment: And what are you expecting ?

Comment: when i select state and submit , i 'm able to get results. but  the selected value is cleared.

Comment: did your state dropdown is in same div i.e. "#district" which you are updating after ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global to hold selected value

```
var selectedDistrict = 0;

$("#district").change(function () {
    selectedDistrict = $("#district").val();
});
```

then do:

```
$("#district")
    .html(data)
    .trigger("chosen:updated")
    .val(selectedDistrict)
    .trigger("chosen:updated");
```

in your ajax success.

Means your code will become:

```
<script>
    var selectedDistrict = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#district").change(function () {
            selectedDistrict = $("#district").val();
        });

        $("#state").change(function () {
        var stateId = $("#state").val()
            phpurl = "sample_url" + stateId;

            $.ajax({
                url: phpurl,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#district").html(data)
                        .trigger("chosen:updated")
                        .val(selectedDistrict)
                        .trigger("chosen:updated");                        
                },
                 error: function(data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```